# Show that $f$($\mathbb{R}$) =($-1$,$1$).

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Consider the function:

$$ f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}  $$
$$ f(x) = \frac{x}{|x|+1} $$

I already showed that this function is continuous and injective.
Maybe this could help? Maybe we can use the intermediate value theorem? The problem is that I don't have an interval [a,b] with a,b $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$. I know that I can consider the limit, but we didn't proved the fact, that I can use the intermediate value theorem for limits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: First show that $|f| < 1$ (this should be pretty easy). Then take any $y \in (-1,1)$ and show that you can explicitly solve $f(x) = y$ for $x$, thereby showing that the image is $(-1,1)$ and nothing else. You might find it helpful to do $y\geq 0$ and $y<0$ separately.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left| f(x) \right|=\left| \frac{x}{|x|+1} \right|= \frac{|x|}{|x|+1}<1$$ thus as $f(x)$ is continuos and lim as $x \rightarrow\pm\infty=\pm1$ $$-1 < f(x) < 1$$

Comment: f is continuos because its a composition of continuos functions and the denominator is never equal to zero; why should be injectivity be important? f is bounded and never can "touch" |1|

Comment: Sorry, never mind, I misread the question as asking to show these things when it said that the asker already showed these things.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just show that there exists a solution in x for any image epsilon-greater than -1, then for any image epsilon-less than 1, then show (trivially) that you can't solve for x when the image is outside of your desired interval, then use continuity and hence IVT to show that the function hits all values in $(-1+\epsilon, 1-\epsilon)$, $\forall \epsilon >0$? Seems like proving continuity was the hardest part.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if wrong:

1) $0\le x:$

$f(x) = \dfrac{x}{|x|+1}= 1- \dfrac{1}{x+1}.$

$x_n:= n$ , $n\in \mathbb{N}.$

$U_n:= [0,1-\dfrac{1}{n+1}],$ and

consider

$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}U_{n}.$

$f$ is continuous, increasing, we have : $f[1,n] =U_n.$

Show that

$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}U_n = [0,1).$

Let $0 \le y \lt 1.$

There is a $n_0$ with $y \lt 1- \dfrac{1}{n_0+1} <1.$

(Details how to choose n_0 are left to do).

Then $y \in U_{n_0}$ for $0 \le y \lt 1$, I.e.

$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} U_n = [0,1).$

2) $ x \le 0$ can be treated similarly.

Comments welcome.